# Collectd Table plugin

Tags: collectd

A quick question relating to CollectD table plugin, 
can I define multiple tables for this plugin to scan?

So having

```
<plugin>
 <table>
   <...>
 </table>
 <table>
  <...>
 </table>
</plugin>
```

Not yet tried it - running up a new test system later this week but seeing if anyone has had experience with multi tables
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is yes
Simply add in a table stanza for the new table as above